# Filling JButton inside a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have a JPanel that acts as topbar for my application, I am trying to design the topbar buttons now, But I am facing an Issue.

[image]

as you can see when I hover over it the red is not filling the panel, I want the red to be a full square. and remain the same size for topbar and icon size. The result I expect is

[image]

as you can see the color is filled within the full bar. I would like to recreate this.

So here is the code as follows a Custom JButtonClass to create the Hover Effect.

```
public class LynxButton extends JButton {
    public LynxButton(){
        super.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }

    public LynxButton(String text) {
        super(text);
        super.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Color pressedColor = ThemeManager.red_LYNX.darker();
        if (getModel().isPressed()) {
            g.setColor(pressedColor);
        } else if (getModel().isRollover()) {
            g.setColor(pressedColor);
        } else {
            g.setColor(getBackground());
        }
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }


    @Override
    public void setContentAreaFilled(boolean b) {
    }
}
```

and then we define the code using

```
    LynxButton exitButton = new LynxButton();
    exitButton.setIcon(...);
    exitButton.setBorder(null);
```

I have tried to set the margin to see if it fixes the issue but again no luck with it.

```
exitButton.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

Edit: Forgot to show the JPanel Defination

```
JPanel buttonContainer = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
```

The `buttonContainer` fills the whole topbar, Confirmed it by removing the call to setBackgroundColor.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the `JPanel` even fills the whole top bar?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Give me a moment, I will confirm that.

Comment: Yes @XtremeBaumer it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't calculate the `hgap` and `vgap` from `FlowLayout` in. Those act like a natural border.

All you need to do is the alter the initialization of your `JPanel` to `new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT), 0, 0)`

Example code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    TestA b = new TestA("X");
    JPanel buttonContainer = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 0, 0));
    buttonContainer.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    buttonContainer.add(b);
    f.add(buttonContainer);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

`TestA` is your `LynxButton`

```
class TestA extends JButton {
    public TestA() {
        super.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }

    public TestA(String text) {
        super(text);
        super.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Color pressedColor = Color.RED;
        if (getModel().isPressed()) {
            g.setColor(pressedColor);
        } else if (getModel().isRollover()) {
            g.setColor(pressedColor);
        } else {
            g.setColor(getBackground());
        }
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentAreaFilled(boolean b) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks It's working but the topbar size shrinks, How can I resolve that?

Comment: Well, The JButton is no longer a square It's a rectangle any idea on how I can fix that?

Comment: Adding `new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)` makes it a square, You can add it to your answer if you want for future comers to the post. :)